# How to make a query with 3 ManyToOne components?

Tags: java, many-to-one

I got a database with a table Result, it looks like this:

Table Result:

> resultId, resultValue, patientId (its a Foreign key of the table Patient), scriptId(Foreign key of ScriptMW), userId(Foreign key of User)

and i forgot the table user has also a foreign key in it, from patientId
so 1 user has more patients....its OneToMany annotation there
all of them are integers

thats what it looks like, and in my java code i got this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer resultId;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

@ManyToOne
private ScriptMW scriptMW;

@ManyToOne
private Patient patient;

@Lob
@Column(length=65536)
private String resultValue;
```

So u can see its 3 times the ManyToOne annotation

Now i need to make a query to get all results of one patient, that belongs to the user, who has used the specific script...

I got the userId, the ScriptId and the patientId as path params, and that works....but now i need to get all the values...and i have no idea how to do it...look at the code below

i cant even select anything from result

```
@Override
public List<Result> getResults(Integer userId, Integer scriptId, Integer patientId) {

    Query q=em.createQuery("Select r From Result r");
    return q.getResultList();

}
```

Once i do the previous code i get this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entities.User.patients, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->entities.Result["user"]->entities.User["patients"])
```

any ideas?

Comment: can you elaborate which of your question related to `jquery`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the problem was with the user

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Patient> patients;
```

He was LAZY (default), but had to be EAGER

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Patient> patients;
```

Once i added it, i used the following query and it worked all...

```
Query q=em.createQuery("Select r From Result r where r.user.userId=:userId and r.scriptMW.scriptId=:scriptId and r.patient.patientId=:patientId")
            .setParameter("userId", userId).setParameter("scriptId", scriptId).setParameter("patientId", patientId);
```

It is an answer to my question, but still i dont like it that it has to be EAGER, has anyone a better way?

Comment: You could also pass entities as parameters, that way your query does not need to know the insides of all those classes. And is that a set of patients in User? How do they connect to the patient in result?

Comment: how should i pass the entities there? And yes, there is a set of patients in user, and in result there is a @ManyToOne annotation with the patient, just a single patient per result.

Comment: `User user,...` in method parameters, `Select r From Result r where r.user = :user` in query and `.setParameter("user", user)`. And you have a single patient in Result, yes, but in result.user.patients a lot more for some reson? Does that make sense in your use case?

Comment: yes, the user is a doctor, and a doctor has more then one patients....so yes, there is a reason for that....and sec i ll try it out

Comment: i just checked, i cant send a whole entities in there bc at that point i just have access to the ids...not to all the other stuff

Comment: I assumed you had them and just passed extracted ids, if not than it's a matter of preference, probably better not to change one query into four.

Comment: I changed all to get the entities, now is just the query making the problems...i ll add an answer to show u what it looks like now...